# What wording should I use to include non-binary pronouns in a contract?

Tags: contract-law, legal-writing

I'm working off of a template for a Terms of Service agreement for an app, and I would like to modify it to use non-binary pronouns (they/their/them) instead of gender-specific pronouns (he/she his/hers him/her). What, if any, language should be included at the head of the contract to explain that they/their/them is referring to a single person rather than a group of people? Right now I'm thinking of something like

> In this document when referring to the Licensee, we use the non-binary
>   and non-gender-specific pronouns “they”, “their”, and “them”. These
>   pronouns are not intended to reflect plurality of the Licensee, and
>   can be replaced by he/his/him or she/her/hers where appropriate to
>   reflect the Licensee’s identity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about the law.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're viewing the use of pronouns and contracts wrong. You are speaking to the Licensee, not some third person. So you would say "You agree to give us all your bases", not "They agree to give us all your bases". If you *were* to use a third person pronoun in describing what the other person is going to do and what you'll do for them, calling the Licensee "they" is positively confusing, and more likely to cause problems. I hope they see my point.

Comment: Didn't realize that was how contracts are typically written, although it makes perfect sense. Much obliged. :)

Comment: And you generally refer to yourself as "me" or "I" (or "we" or "us" if you are a group or corporation). Both these usages should be spelled out when you identify the licensee/licensor

Comment: Contracts can be written in the "we - you" form. It is quite common when using a set of standard terms you don't intend to negotiate. Hence on websites it is common. Whether you do it that way or not is a matter of style.

Answer (score 8):

To be clear, you would *once* at the beginning of the contract define for example who the Licensee and the Licensor are, and then use these terms everywhere throughout the contract. Avoid pronouns since they are inherently vague, and you don't want that in a contract. If you think this makes the language clumsy, because the contract says "Licensee" two hundred times, that's fine. It's a contract, not a novel.

Comment: I recommend avoiding "Licensee" and "Licensor" as party names. It often leads to confusion. There are better approaches - eg by giving them actual names. That requires some global replacement in some cases. If the template is being used frequently there are other approaches still.

Comment: Normally, the licensor is going to be the same in each version, so "BIG CORP" for that, and "Licensee" for the other party, would usually be clear. Credit card agreements often use "BIG BANK" or "BANK" to refer to themselves, and "YOU"  to refer to the customer, in their customer agreements, which isn't confusing. In a lease "LANDLORD" and "TENANT" or in a purchase and sale agreement "SELLER" and "BUYER' are often good terms to use.

Comment: @FrancisDavey Do you mean because the words are quite similar? So I might write "LICENSee" when I actually meant "LICENSor"?

Comment: @gnasher729 - yes. Precisely. In my experience (of licence negotiation) that often happens. Even uses like "The Company" and "The Contractor" can get confusing, especially when reviewing agreements quickly. If a party is called "Cool Beans Ltd" then referring to them as "Cool Beans" is clear. As I said elsewhere sometimes a "we" v "you" format is another option.

Comment: @FrancisDavey absolutely agree. The fourth time I renewed my lease, I realized that the contract had mistakenly written that "**Lessee** shall provide the leased premises in good condition," when it should obviously have read "**Lessor** shall provide the leased premises in good condition." After all, providing the leased premises is what makes them the lessor. I'd already signed versions of that contract three times without noticing the mistake, and I have no idea how many times before that the landlord used the same contract with nobody noticing the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

### Forget Pronouns, call them by function.

Typical contracts assign names to the parties, and that evades the whole pronoun and misgendering problem from the root.

> This contract conveys a license from Alice Corp (hereafter: The Corporation) to the undersigning User (hereafter: User). All User's bases are be assigned to The Corporation. In return, The Corporation grants User the right to use The Corporation's word processing software package.

Whenever you speak about the rights or duties of the party, you use the assigned name.

Answer (score -5):

What is the motivation for this question? In general I don’t think that using irregular and politically/aesthetically motivated language has any legal effect on the substance of a contract. In general legal writing and especially contracts are drafted with the object of avoiding as much ambiguity as at all possible. Using politically-motivated idiosyncratic pronouns would only serve to cloud and convolute the meaning of the contract and so I don’t think would ever be advisable. If one still insists on doing it then I don’t think it would have any legal effect on the function of the contract therefore making this a question more suited for English.SE (“how can I compose a note that renders my irregular if not erroneous use of they/then pronouns equivalent to what one would understand from more regular singular ones?”) in practice the answer is quite obvious; one would preface with a note that “This document uses they/them pronouns throughout which are to be read as would be standard singular (he/him, she/her) pronouns in the same place.” But then of course you potentially run into the problems of further ambiguity as far as: what do you then say when you actually want to use a Plural pronoun?